# I am getting Undefined offset error php

Tags: php

I am trying to split the Content that is fetching from DB a few words next to image and a remaining content in the below paragraph

I am getting undefined offset error : 41

the below is the code... it executes correctly but with notice error as above... Can you please help me to fix it.

```
<div class="contentfont" style="padding-left:20px; text-align:left;">
<?php 

$words = explode(" ",$dcontent);
$cntWords = count($words); 
$splitWords = round($cntWords/2);

for ($i=0;$i<=$splitWords;$i++)
{
print $words[$i].' ';
$halfPoint = $i;
}
?>

<p class="contentfont" style="padding-top:10px;">
<?php 
for ($i=$halfPoint;$i<=$cntWords;$i++) 
{
print $words[$i].' ';// This print statement is causing me this error     Notice: Undefined offset: 41 in D:\xampp\htdocs\training\admin-panel\php\sai_devotees_detail.php on line 106
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Format your code correctly and someone may be willing to help you. Also, people aren't mind readers. You need to provide where the error is occuring and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined offset in this case means you are reading past the length of the $words array. Try $cntWords - 1 for ceiling of the loop like this:

```
for ($i = $halfway; $i <= $cntWords -1; $i++) {
```

$halfPoint = $i; is also outside the loop. Try this instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $splitWords; $i++) {
    print $words[$i] . ' ';
    $halfPoint = $i;
}
```

When you make a loop in PHP without brackets, only the first statement after it will be executed. So in this case, $i doesn't exist for you to assign it to $halfPoint. Don't think it's clever to compact everything into one line. It will only cause you problems.

Comment: If i put the content inside the loop also there is no difference still i am getting the notice error